# Verify Cauchy's integral theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I was asked to verify Cauchy's integral theorem when $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+2}$ and $\gamma$ is the circle $|z+1|=\frac{1}{2}$. I have tried various ways and eventually it leads to complicated integration.

This is my approach, but I don't know how to continue on.
We parametrize the circle as $\gamma(t)=-1+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$. Then $\gamma^{'}(t)=\frac{1}{2}ie^{it}$. Then $$\oint_{\gamma}f(z)dz=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{(-1+\frac{1}{2}e^{it})^2+2}\frac{1}{2}ie^{it}dt=\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{2ie^{it}}{e^{2it}-4e^{it}+12}dt$$ and then I was stucked at here.

Is there any hint so that I can proceed this question ? Thank you.

Comment: So you need to show the integral is zero. Parameterise the circle, integrate on $[0, 2\pi]$, and go.

Comment: this is the method i used, but it ends up with very complex integration. I parametrize the circle as $\gamma(t)=-1+\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$

Comment: Edit the original post and show your work.

Comment: @SeanRoberson , edited.

Comment: The function has an antiderivative in the centered Disc in $-1$ with radius $0.5$. Thus the integral is zero.